# Show that $\frac {1}{k\cdot(k-1)} = \frac {1}{k-1} - \frac {1}{k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

This is my first question on math. Hopefully I won't make any blunders.

I have to show that $$\frac {1}{k\cdot(k-1)} = \frac {1}{k-1} - \frac {1}{k}$$ is true yet I don't even know how to start. Anyone got any clues for me?

Cheers

Comment: study partial fractions

Comment: why not just bring the rhs on a common denominator???

Comment: Sorry, yeah, should have been $\frac {1}{k-1} - \frac {1}{k}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{k-k+1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{k}{k(k-1)}-\frac{k-1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$$
or (from the RHS to the LHS)
$$\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac1k=\frac{1\cdot k-1\cdot(k-1)}{k(k-1)}=\frac{k-k+1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{1}{k(k-1)}$$

Comment: How do you get the first transformation?

Comment: Because $k-k=0$.

Comment: Duh, I feel so dumb 